# PHP - Detect the incoming url requesting php page from another source/url

Tags: php, url

Is there a way in which I can detect the URL that is calling in my php page, similar to say a GET or POST but would like to get the URL as I would like to restrict the page accessing it to a certain URL as this file is being called from another server.

Basically: www.MYURL.com calls the php file from say www.PHPURL.com if the URL is NOT www.MYURL.com then bounce them out etc.

Many Thanks

In response to the answers below I used the as mentioend and here is what I did:

```
  $URL_REF = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  $URL_REF_HOST =   $URL_REF['host'];
```

Thanks @Philip Bevan,@Itai Sagi and @EvilP

Comment: As mentioned by @Itai Sagi, it's not a good idea to make your privilege routing based on this. Also, you can achieve the same functionality by using: `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_PATH)`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

well, you could use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` - but it can be cloaked/removed.

EDIT: as someone asked, the HTTP_REFERER is a header which is sent by the client, most browsers default behavior is to send it, but if you'd like, you can disable it or even send a different referer header so people will think you come from some place else.

the bottom line: if it isn't THAT critical for you, you can use it, but don't EVER, EVER give people extra privileges based on their referer alone.

Comment: could you encrypt the header using this technique?

Comment: you answered first so will give this to you, many thanks for this.

Answer (score 11):

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

is what you are looking for.